# Returning the lenght of a vector idiomatically

Tags: go

I'm writing a function that returns a sequence of numbers of variable length:

```
func fib(n int) ??? {
    retval := ???
    a, b := 0, 1
    for ; n > 0; n-- {
        ??? // append a onto retval here
        c := a + b
        a = b
        b = c
    }
}
```

It can be observed that the final length of the returned sequence will be `n`. How and what should `fib` return to achieve idiomatic Go? If the length was not known in advance, how would the return value, and usage differ? How do I insert values into `retval`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, we know how many numbers; we want n Fibonacci numbers.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fib(n int) (f []int) {
    if n < 0 {
        n = 0
    }
    f = make([]int, n)
    a, b := 0, 1
    for i := 0; i < len(f); i++ {
        f[i] = a
        a, b = b, a+b
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    f := fib(7)
    fmt.Println(len(f), f)
}
```

Output: 7 [0 1 1 2 3 5 8]

---

Here, we don't know how many numbers; we want all the Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to n.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibMax(n int) (f []int) {
    a, b := 0, 1
    for a <= n {
        f = append(f, a)
        a, b = b, a+b
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    f := fibMax(42)
    fmt.Println(len(f), f)
}
```

Output: 10 [0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34]

---

You could also use [IntVector](http://golang.org/pkg/container/vector/#IntVector) from the Go [vector package](http://golang.org/pkg/container/vector/). Note that `type IntVector []int`.

Comment: You can name the return value and do stuff with it?! That's awesome!

Comment: "Within a list of [function] parameters or results, the names (IdentifierList) must either all be present or all be absent. If present, each name stands for one item (parameter or result) of the specified type; if absent, each type stands for one item of that type. Parameter and result lists are always parenthesized except that if there is exactly one unnamed result it may be written as an unparenthesized type." http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Function_types

Comment: "The result parameters act as ordinary local variables and the function may assign values to them as necessary. ...  all the result values are initialized to the zero values for their type upon entry to the function." http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Return_statements

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Vectors, use slices. [Here are some mapping of various vector operations to idiomatic slice operations](http://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/eh3gh/slice_support_and_containervector/).